# Can I rely on my companions' behavior?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Since the companion configuration in DA:I is not as in-depth as it was in the previous parts of the series I feel very uncomfortable when only controlling my own character.

In the behavior screen I can only enable or disable their "automatic" behavior and set thresholds for mana/stamina, potions, etc.

Will my characters use the best utility skills based on the current situation? I.e. will a mage do an AOE attack when multiple enemies are standing close to each other? Or is the AI not that good? If an enemy has an elemental weakness will a mage use specific spells (if equipped) particularly suiting that weakness?

Comment: I didn't play for a while, but I think it will only depend on what you input in their tactics menu - and without tinkering they will not be at the top of their game

Comment: I remember defeating dragons in Nightmare difficulty as Knight Enchanter and Champion without ever switching to my companions. But to be fair, both builds were fairly overpowered, so I have no idea if my companions were actually capable or not. They did die a lot, though, forcing me to revive them every now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience as a rogue and a mage my companions were very capable and always had my back. I didn't feel like I had to run in an kill everything for them. I've never felt the need to switch to my companions because they're not doing well on they're own. 
Example: I had Dorian in my party a lot and if we were getting surrounded almost always he used an AOE attack to set most of them on fire. Worked quite well.